# Java - access pom.xml file from JAR

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm working on a plugin capable of displaying the list of the dependencies of a Maven project. To make this possible, I read the pom.xml file and print data on the console for debugging. This worked just fine, until I tried it from the JAR file : I got a FileNotFoundException (for the pom.xml file)

- Is there a better way to list dependencies of a Maven project ?
- How to read pom.xml when we are inside the JAR file ?

[Here is my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48167317/java-how-to-list-the-dependencies/48168152?noredirect=1#comment83394340_48168152)

Comment: You need to show the code that you're using. But the big tip is that you cannot read resources from the classpath as `java.io.File` objects because there are no "files" inside a jar/

Comment: I can't because my code is on another computer in my company and I can't move the data to my personal computer. I used the code specified in my original question with small upgrades, but this is not important here. I have to use `InputStream` ? And if yes, how can I call `InputStream` when it's on the jar file and how can I use `File` from `java.io` when it's not running from the Jar file ?

Comment: You can try to read the pom.xml as resource.

Comment: I works when I want to read the pom.xml as resource, but I have to specify the path and it's dynamic : `META-INF/maven/{groupId}/{artifactId}/pom.xml`. I don't know how to get these two specific data at runtime

Comment: You know some things like mvn dependency:tree ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am aware of that but I can't use it. The main goal is to list dependencies on `dev` and `prod` environements. Maven is not installed here, so it is not possible to run a `mvn` command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested [JF Meier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/927493/jf-meier), I tried to read the pom.xml file as a resource and it worked.

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
InputStream pomFile = obj.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/maven/groupId/artifactId/pom.xml");
```

The only issue now is that the path to the file will not be the same for each project as it depends of the `groupId` and the `artifactId`

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was

```
$ unzip foo.jar foo
$ cat foo/META-INF/maven/com.bar/foo/pom.xml
```

Another idea that didn't work for me instead of `unzip`ping is `jar -xf foo.jar`